# Choosing $a, b$ such that $f$ is differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $ f(x):= \Bigl \{
\frac{3}{x-3}$ if $x\leq 2$

$ax^2+b+2x$  if $x \gt 2$

So what i said is the function has to be continous. So i said $\frac{3}{2-3}=-3=4a+4+b$

Then i said the left derivative and the right should be equal. I dont know if this is the right solution. The definition of differentiable doesnt mention left and right hand limits.

It follows by taking derivatives 
$-3=4a$

My question is: Are my thoughts correct? What are requirements for a piecewise function to be differentiable?
Sorry i couldnt format the piecewise function correctly

Comment: I think you made an error in taking the derivative of $ax^2+b+2x$?  Did you substitute $x = 2$ in $2x$ too early?

Comment: But otherwise, your reasoning is valid.  You need continuity (so the two values need to match at $x = 2$) and you need the derivatives to match as well.

Comment: Wouldnt the derivative be $2ax+2$ which is  at $x=2$ $4a+2$ ?

Comment: It would indeed.  But your post currently has "It follows by taking derivatives $-3 = 4a$," not "$-3 = 4a+2$."

Comment: Yes i noticed thank you. Could you also give an intuition why the derivatives from left and right have to be equal. This doesnt follow from the definition of differentiability ? You can post this as an answer if you wish.

Comment: Well, the derivatives represent the instantaneous slopes of each piece at $x = 2$, and if they're not equal, the slopes of the two pieces will be different, and they'll meet at a corner (which indicates a point where the stitched function isn't differentiable), instead of a straight line, as they should.  Does that help?

Comment: Yes but how could i understand this just by the definition of differentiability ? The defintion where h->0 and you find the limit. Thank you

Comment: If they don't match, then the two-sided limit doesn't exist and therefore the function is not differentiable.

Comment: Thank you i think i got it. So the limit exists only if the twosided limit exists ?

Comment: Yes; in this context, you can assume such limits to be two-sided, unless otherwise noted.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please post this as an answer so i can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Posted as an answer by request of the OP.]

In order for the function to be differentiable, the values of the two pieces must be equal at $x = 2$, and the derivatives of the two pieces must also be equal at $x = 2$.

The former condition tells us that

$$
\left. \frac{3}{x-3} \,\right|_{x=2} = \boxed{-3 = 4a+4+b} = \left. (ax^2+2x+b)\, \right|_{x=2}
$$

and the latter condition tells us that

$$
\left. \frac{d}{dx} \, \frac{3}{x-3} \, \right|_{x=2} = \left. -\frac{3}{(x-3)^2} \, \right|_{x=2} = \boxed{-3 = 4a+2} = \left. (2ax+2) \,\right|_{x=2} = \left. \frac{d}{dx}\, (ax^2+2x+b)\, \right|_{x=2}
$$

Then solving the two equations

$$
4a+b = -7 \\
4a = -5
$$

yields the proper coefficients for the pieces to match.